# How to return calling object from mocked pandas function

Tags: python, pandas, mocking, pytest-mock

I am attempting to write a test (using pytest-mock) for some code that uses pandas for I/O. Ideally instead of writing the contents to a file using pandas`.to_excel()` function, I would rather return the dataframe to my test function for comparison.

So my questions are:

1. Is what I want even possible
2. If so, how do I return the dataframe from the code under test to my test function

Here's my code so far.

### mymodule.py

```
def my_module_func(input_file: Path, dbc: DBConnection) -> None:

    
    db_data = dbc.get_from_db()


    spreadsheet_data = pandas.read_excel(input_file, engine='openpyxl')
    
    # Do some stuff to modify the spreadsheet_data dataframe


    # Generate the path to the output file and write updated info to it
    output_name = f"{input_file.stem}_Checked{input_file.suffix}"
    output_file = input_file.parent.joinpath(output_name)

    spreadsheet_data.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
```

### test_mymodule.py

```
from mymodule import my_module_func

dummy_data = {'values': ['val1']}

@pytest.fixture()
def fake_file():
    return Path("./mocked.xlsx")

def test_my_func(mocker, fake_file)
     # Patch the db class function so we don't actually hit the db
    mock_db_connector = mocker.patch('mymodule.DBConnection', autospec=True)
    mock_db_connector.get_from_db.return_value = ["val1", "val2"]

    # Patch the pandas read function for getting the data from the input file
    mocker.patch('mymodule.pandas.read_excel', return_value=DataFrame(data=dummy_data))

    # Patch the pandas to_excel function for writing data to file
    # Ideally I'd like to tell this to return the dataframe instead of write it
    output_patch = mocker.patch('mymodule.pandas.DataFrame.to_excel')

    my_module_func(fake_file, mock_db_connector)

    # End Goal
    # pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal(actual, expected)
```

Comment: would it be acceptable to use a pytest `tmp_path` to write and read from instead of mocking here? Here's example usage from the documentation https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html

Comment: @mitoRibo I was hoping to avoid it if there was a better solution, but I plan to do something similar as a fallback option